# How to Animate a Path Forwards and Backwards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have animated a UIBezier Path to go around a circle and change its stroke color whilst doing so. When it goes all the way around, I would like it go all the way around in the opposite direction.

Here is the code that makes it go forwards:

```
 [CATransaction begin];
    {
        [CATransaction setAnimationDuration: 3.0];//Dynamic Duration
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
            [tutorialCircle removeFromSuperlayer];
            tutorialCircle.opacity = 0.0;
            strokePart.opacity = 0.0;
            [strokePart removeFromSuperlayer];
        }];

        const double portion = 1.0 / ((double)3);

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            strokePart = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            strokePart.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
            strokePart.frame = tutorialCircle.bounds;
            strokePart.path = tutorialCircle.path;
            strokePart.lineCap = tutorialCircle.lineCap;
            strokePart.lineWidth = tutorialCircle.lineWidth;

            if (i == 0) {
                strokePart.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
            }

            else if (i == 1) {
                strokePart.strokeColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
            }

            else if (i == 2) {
                strokePart.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
            }
            strokePart.strokeStart = i * portion;
            strokePart.strokeEnd = (i + 1) * portion;

            [tutorialCircle addSublayer: strokePart];

            animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"strokeEnd"];
            NSArray* times = @[ @(0.0), // Note: This works because both the times and the stroke start/end are on scales of 0..1
                                @(strokePart.strokeStart),
                                @(strokePart.strokeEnd),
                                @(1.0) ];
            NSArray* values = @[ @(strokePart.strokeStart),
                                 @(strokePart.strokeStart),
                                 @(strokePart.strokeEnd),
                                 @(strokePart.strokeEnd) ];

            animation.keyTimes = times;
            animation.values = values;
            animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
            animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
            [animation setDelegate:self];
            [strokePart addAnimation: animation forKey: @"whatever"];
        }
    }
    [CATransaction commit];
```

So in my animationDidStop delegate method for the first animation, I know I'd be calling the second animation to go backwards, however, I am struggling to create the animation for this to go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

`animation.autoreverses = YES`

Comment: Yes it does almost exactly what I want but it flashes different colors when it comes back